# In python how can I match two lists of tuples by a tuple element?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have `names` as a list of tuples that contain name tuples in arbitrary order:

```
names = [(1,"Alice"), (2,"Bob")]
```

and `genders` as another list of tuples that contain gender tuples in arbitrary order:

```
genders = [(2,"male"), (1,"female")]
```

How can I effectively match the two lists by using the first elements of the tuples as a key to get:

```
result = [("Alice","female"), ("Bob","male")]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy one-liner answer, runs slowly:

```
[(name, gender) for (id0, gender) in genders for (id1, name) in names if id0==id1]
```

Better answer (see Ignazio's response):

```
namedict = dict(names)
genderdict = dict(genders)
[(namedict[id], genderdict[id]) for id in set(namedict) & set(genderdict)]
```

Comment: That is `O(n^2)` whereas creating dictionaries first and iterating is `O(3n) ~ O(n)`... just saying, you don't want to do this for long lists.

Answer (score 7):

Convert to dictionaries, gather the keys, and iterate.